# Adding div using ajax and jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

How would I create a div that when clicked sends an ajax call to a jsp page to replace the content of the div that has been clicked while adding a css class to the changed div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the div in the view:

`<div id="a" class="a" onclick="clickFunc()">...</div>`

the javascript function:

`function clickFunc() {$("#a").load("whatever.jsp"); $("#a").addClass("newClass");}`

Hope this is what your looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

and then:

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
    $(this).load('/bar.jsp', function() {
        $('#foo').addClass('foobar');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest not to use self closing tags, as `IE 7 & 6` do not support those; so please use the closing tag `</div>`

Comment: never heard of live i prefer sticking to the onClick in the div tag like @nayish suggested, thanks anyways...

Comment: @Muki, the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method allows you to attach an event handler to a DOM element which would persist even if you replace the contents of this element.

Comment: @Muki I'd suggest that you go with this method, as the `live` method solves the purpose that you are looking for.